# Who can explain why the results of these two consoles are the same?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, new-object

This is a constructor function,and it has two instance object,then I change them with different depth,but result I can't understand.if someone encounter this problem,hope you can help me,thanks.

```js
let C = function () {}
C.prototype = Object.create({
  option: {
    name: 'c'
  }
})

let c1 = new C()
let c2 = new C()

c1.option.name = 'new_c'
console.log(c2.option.name)
// --> new_c

c1.option = null
console.log(c2.option.name)
// --> new_c
```

Comment: `c1.option = null` creates a new property on `c1`. You should be able to see the difference using  `console.log(c1, c2);`

Answer (score 0):

When you **read** a property from an object, and the object doesn't have that property, then JavaScript will seek up the prototype chain.

When you **write** a property to an object, then it will just be written to that object. It **won't** seek up the prototype chain to see if it exists and then overwrite the value further up the chain.

So `c2.option.name` fails to find `option` on `c2`, looks at the prototype and gets `C.prototype`. Then it reads `name` from that.

`c1.option = null` replaces `option` on `c1` but doesn't touch the `option` on `c2` so `c2.option` still points to the same object.

Comment: Perfect！The explanation is very easy to understand. Thank you.